# How to run a function after one is done (or after an item in an array loads)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, callback

I'm trying to animate a chat. I have a function that loads the blue messages one at a time each time you press the input field/button. Now, I want the grey messages to appear one at a time automatically **after the LAST blue message appears**. The JS code I have now has them appearing automatically  after the first blue message instead (with a one second delay).

HTML

```
        <div class="messages">
                    <div class="blue invisible" id="msg1">Hi! I'm looking for an old friend. She attended Martin Grove a few years ago.</div>
                    <div class="blue invisible" id="msg2">Her name is Sam. *insert pic of Sam and MC*</div>
                    <div class="blue invisible" id="msg3">Did you know her or her last name by any chance? </div>
                    <div class="grey" id="msg4" style="display: none;">Hello there!</div>
                    <div class="grey" id="msg5" style="display: none;">Unfortunately, I did not have the pleasure of teaching Sam. Her last name and whereabouts are a mystery to me as well. </div> 
    </div>
    
                <div class="input" id="chat-button" onClick="showMessage()">
                    
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
const myHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("invisible");
const HTMLElementsArr = [...myHTMLCollection];

function blueMessage() {
    if (HTMLElementsArr.length > 0) {
        HTMLElementsArr.shift().classList.remove('invisible');
        greyMessage();
    }
}


function greyMessage() {
    setTimeout("show_second()", 1000);
}

function show_second() {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout("show_third()", 1000);
}

function show_third() {
    document.getElementById("msg5").style.display = "block";
}
```

[image: animated chat]

Answer (score 1):

Call `greyMessage()` only when the array is empty, so replace:

```
greyMessage()
```

with:

```
if (!HTMLElementsArr.length) greyMessage();
```

As a side note, it is bad practice to pass a string as callback argument to `setTimeout`. Pass the function object (without parentheses). So, for example, replace:

```
setTimeout("show_second()", 1000);
```

with:

```
setTimeout(show_second, 1000);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! I'm new to JS, so I really appreciate your help and notes